# Ajax error on retrieving values using ms mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have these codes:

**Contact Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace mvccrud
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ContactMetaData))]
    public partial class Contact
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Person required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Contact Person")]
        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact No required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Contact No")]
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country required")]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State required")]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public int StateID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ContactsController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace mvccrud.Controllers
{
    public class ContactsController : Controller
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get All Contacts
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Views/Contacts/Index</returns>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Contact> allContacts = null;
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = (from a in dc.Contacts
                         join b in dc.Countries on a.CountryID equals b.CountryID
                         join c in dc.States on a.StateID equals c.StateID
                         select new
                         {
                             a,
                             b.CountryName,
                             c.StateName
                         });
                if (v != null)
                {
                    allContacts = new List<Contact>();
                    foreach (var i in v)
                    {
                        Contact c = i.a;
                        c.CountryName = i.CountryName;
                        c.StateName = i.StateName;
                        allContacts.Add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(allContacts);  
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create and Update part of the CRUD
        /// Populate the Country List
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Countries in Descending Order</returns>
        private List<Country> GetCountry()
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return dc.Countries.OrderBy(a => a.CountryName).ToList();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populate the State List
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="countryID"></param>
        /// <returns>State name based on the countryID</returns>
        private List<State> GetState(int countryID)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return dc.States.Where(a => a.CountryID.Equals(countryID)).OrderBy(a => a.StateID).ToList();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the state list but in JSON Format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="countryID"></param>
        /// <returns>state list in Json format</returns>
        public JsonResult GetStateList(int countryID)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {

                return new JsonResult { Data = GetState(countryID), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populate contacts information from database based on contactID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="contactID"></param>
        /// <returns>contact information</returns>
        public Contact GetContact(int contactID)
        {
            Contact contact = null;
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = (from a in dc.Contacts
                         join b in dc.Countries on a.CountryID equals b.CountryID
                         join c in dc.States on a.StateID equals c.StateID
                         where a.ContactID.Equals(contactID)
                         select new
                         {
                             a,
                             b.CountryName,
                             c.StateName
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    contact = v.a;
                    contact.CountryName = v.CountryName;
                    contact.StateName = v.StateName;
                }
                return contact;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// updating contact information
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns>View/Contacts/Save</returns>
        public ActionResult Save(int id = 0)
        {
            List<Country> country = GetCountry();
            List<State> states = new List<State>();
            if (id > 0)
            {
                //Update
                var c = GetContact(id);
                if (c != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(country, "CountryID", "CountryName", c.CountryID);
                    ViewBag.States = new SelectList(GetState(c.CountryID), "StateID", "StateName", c.StateID);
                }
                else
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(c);
            }
            else
            {
                //Create 
                ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(country, "CountryID", "CountryName");
                ViewBag.States = new SelectList(states, "StateID", "StateName");
                return View();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// save created contact
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <returns>View/Contacts/Save</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save(Contact c)
        {
            string message = "";
            bool status = false;

            //Save 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    if (c.ContactID > 0)
                    {
                        //Update
                        var v = dc.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactID.Equals(c.ContactID)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (v != null)
                        {
                            v.ContactPerson = c.ContactPerson;
                            v.ContactNo = c.ContactNo;
                            v.CountryID = c.CountryID;
                            v.StateID = c.StateID;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return HttpNotFound();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Add new 
                        dc.Contacts.Add(c);
                    }
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Error! Please try again.";
                ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(GetCountry(), "CountryID", "CountryName", c.CountryID);
                ViewBag.States = new SelectList(GetState(c.CountryID), "StateID", "StateName", c.StateID);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = status;
            return View(c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Save.chstml**

```
@model mvccrud.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Save";
}

<h2>Save</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Contacts", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.ContactID)
        }

        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.ContactPerson)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ContactPerson)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.ContactNo)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ContactNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ContactNo)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.CountryID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.CountryID, ViewBag.Countries as SelectList, "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CountryID)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(a => a.StateID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.StateID, ViewBag.States as SelectList, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.StateID)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @style = "padding-left:50px; font-weight:bold;" })
}

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#CountryID').change(function () {
                var countryID = $(this).val();
                var $state = $('#StateID');
                $state.empty();
                $state.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Please Wait...'));

                if (countryID =="") {
                    $state.empty();
                    $state.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select State'));
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Contacts/GetStateList',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { 'countryID': countryID },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (d) {
                        $state.empty();
                        $state.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select State'));
                        $.each(d, function (i, val) {
                            $state.append($('<option></option>').val(val.StateID).html(val.StateName));
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

When you select a country in the countries dropdown list, the states dropdownlist should populate with the states. This is not so with mine. I only get the 500 error when I get the ajax data.
When I inspect the element, this is what I get:

```
GET http://localhost:5826/Contacts/GetStateList?countryID=5 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9536
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
(anonymous) @ Save:108
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:557
browserLink:37 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ browserLink:37
ajax @ browserLink:37
ajaxAbort @ browserLink:62
abort @ browserLink:62
stop @ browserLink:62
(anonymous) @ browserLink:62
dispatch @ browserLink:37
h @ browserLink:37
Navigated to http://localhost:5826/Contacts/Save
jquery-3.1.1.js:3846 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function
    at Object.parse (http://localhost:5826/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:211:18)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5826/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:379:28)
    at mightThrow (http://localhost:5826/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:3570:29)
    at process (http://localhost:5826/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:3638:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3846
process @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3642
jquery-3.1.1.js:3855 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function
    at Object.parse (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:211)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:379)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
    at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)
parse @ jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:211
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:379
mightThrow @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3570
process @ jquery-3.1.1.js:3638
jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 GET http://localhost:5826/Contacts/GetStateList?countryID=5 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9536
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.js:9143
(anonymous) @ Save:108
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:557
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GetState` method replace the return with:

```
return Json(new { Data = GetState(countryID) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

On your success method you shoud have also `d.Data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Contacts/GetStateList',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'countryID': countryID },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d) {
        $state.empty();
        $state.append($('<option></option>').val('').html('Select State'));
        $.each(d.Data, function (i, item) {
            $state.append($('<option></option>').val(item.StateID).html(item.StateName));
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```